# C# mvc datatables not expecting for each var in Item any solution for this?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, foreach, datatables

I am trying to display a details table using datatables but getting following error. 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UID1Z.png)

For this my ViewModel look like this

```
     public class EquipmentDetailsViewModel
    {
        public int Equipment_Id { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<EquipmentServiceHistoryListViewModel> Service_History { get; set; }
}
```

my controller look like this:

```
    public ActionResult JsonDetails(int Id)
    {
        Equipment e = _repo.GetSingle(Id);

        var model = AutoMapper.Mapper.Map<Equipment, EquipmentDetailsViewModel>(e);

        JsonResult jsonModel = new JsonResult()
        {
            Data = model,
            ContentEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8,
            ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet,
            MaxJsonLength = Int32.MaxValue
        };

        return jsonModel;

    }
    public ActionResult Details(int Id)
    {
        return View();
    }
```

in the view for this controller i am using following table:

```
@using Project.ViewModels;
@model EquipmentDetailsViewModel
<table id="dataTable" class="datatables table table-striped table-hover ">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>
                Service No
            </th>
            <th>
                Service Due Date
            </th>
            <th>
                Service Completed Date
            </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
```

and

```
@foreach (var item in Model.Service_History)
    {
          <tr>
                    <td>
                       @Html.DisplayFor(model => item.Service_No)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(model => item.Sevice_Due_Date)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(model=> item.Service_Completed_Date)
                    </td>  
                </tr>
               }
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

My JS is setup something like below

```
    @section scripts{

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('.datatables').DataTable({
                "lengthMenu": [[25, 50, -1], [25, 50, "All"]],
                 "ajax": {
                    "url": '/Service_History/JsonDetails/',
                    "dataSrc": ""
                },
                "deferRender": true,
                "columns": [
                    {
                        data: 'Service_No',
                        visible: false
                    },


                    { data: 'Service_Due_Date',
                        render: function (data, type, row) {                           
                            if (type === 'display' || type === 'filter') {

                                return (moment(data).format("DD/MM/YYYY"));
                            }                           
                            return data;
                        }
                    },

                    {
                        data: 'Service_Completed_Date',
                        render: function (data, type, row) {
                            if (type === 'display' || type === 'filter') {
                                return (moment(data).format("DD/MM/YYYY"));
                            }                        
                            return data;
                        }
                    }                    
                ],
                "order": [] //prevent auto sorting on first column
            });
});


    </script>

}
```

Can anybody suggest me what alternative of For each var in Item
can  i use to make this page work. 
Thanks

Comment: That's not an error message.  It's just a reference to a line of code.  In what context are you seeing that?  What's the actual problem?

Comment: You are returning a json result and the view separate it looks like. The view is not being supplied a model from what I can see so Service_History is never instantiated. Leaving this as a comment as I don't think I have the whole picture. Can you elaborate or show where you are setting the view model?

Comment: `public ActionResult Details(int Id)
    {
        return View();
    }` doesn't return any model data. This is the place where the model that is used when the page loads should be declared. The foreach Razor syntax is interpreted by the server based on the model data you (should) supply in this method. I assume the JsonDetails method is only for use with some ajax call, so this will be called at another time. Set some breakpoints and see what is actually being executed in your code.

Comment: actually, having seen your edit... if you are loading the data via ajax immediately when the table is created, then you probably don't need the Razor `foreach` at all. If the user just waits a moment or two after loading the data will be fetched via ajax, right?

Comment: Thanks for your response.I am using foreach loop as in my viewmodel i have IEnumerable list of service history viewmodel. If i don't use foreach loop in view the table does not recognise IEnumerable fields name.

Comment: "in my viewmodel i have IEnumerable list of service history viewmodel". yes, but you are not sending this viewmodel to the page when it's loaded. The model will be empty, which is why you get an error. You only send a model when the JsonDetails method is called via ajax. When I said "remove the foreach", I meant everything inside it as well.

Answer (score 3):

It appears you are trying to get the results from the client and are not looking to load any data from the server.

Therefore the foreach loop is not needed. Your datatables call to your JsonResult function should suffice, however looking at the code you are not passing the ID parameter to the endpoint in the javascript.

When attempting use razor remember that processing is done on the server side and as such

Would require

```
    public ActionResult Details(int Id)
    {
        return View();
    }
```

To become

```
public ActionResult Details(int Id)
{
   var viewmodel = _repo.GetSingle(Id);
    return View(viewmodel );
}
```

I would also add a non null check for service_history before the foreach loop

Comment: Thanks for your response. The problem is i am using public IEnumerable<EquipmentServiceHistoryListViewModel> Service_History { get; set; } to get service history in detail page of each equipment and for each loop is required in order to get service history view model  fields.

Comment: Yes but you are loading the page without a model meaning that Service_History is null as it is an object that has not been instantiated. If you are not looking to populate the page on the server you can remove the foreach entirely and just let Datatables handle the population. though you will need to set the query parameter in the url

Comment: The problem is when i remove the for each loop then data table does not recognize the fields name and does not handle data.  The way you suggesting, it works if i don't have an IEnumerable list.

Comment: I do not beleive the data attribute is needed when  you are returning data from the render function.

Also you do not have a parameter on your ajax url property

Comment: "The problem is when i remove the for each loop then data table does not recognize the fields name and does not handle data". As I've pointed out above, SCFi means to remove the foreach loop _and everything inside it_. It's not needed because Datatables loads the table data via ajax when the page is created.